# How can I force a reboot during .NET Framework v4.0 setup?

Tags: .net, windows-7, .net-4.0, installation

I am basically trying to find answer to the very same question as in [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2006/06/13/627729.aspx):

> How can I force a reboot during .NET Framework setup to make sure my setup will handle it correctly?

I did exactly what the guy advised:

1. I have win7 with <.NET v4.0 installed (v3.5 by default on win7),
2. I lock the file mscorier.dll in sys32 directory using [lock.exe](https://onedrive.live.com/?cid=27e6a35d1a492af7&id=27E6A35D1A492AF7%21505),
3. run the .NET v4.0 installer downloaded from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17718).

However, installation finishes just fine and no reboot is required! How can I force .NET v4.0 installer to require a reboot once it is done? Any idea on different file which I should lock for writing?

I basically want to see what happens after I postpone required reboot and try to run either .NET4.0 app or .NETv4.0 windows service. The linked article says:

> You may see unpredictible behavior in your application if it is attempting to run on top of a version of the .NET Framework that needed a reboot at the end of setup and the reboot has not yet happened.

But I would rather see for myself... For the record, I scrolled down to discussion in the linked article and there is an advice to lock the mscoree.dll in %windir%\syswow64 folder for 64bit Windows, but that did not help either, installation completed fine.

Comment: You probably couldn't pick a more obscure DLL.  It has something to do with configuring Internet Explorer, allowing it to run unsigned .NET assemblies.  The odds that you'll notice it not being updated yet are zilch.  Pick mscoree.dll, every .NET app needs that one.  Watch out for bitness.  Nobody is going to check if your lock.exe actually works.

Comment: @Hans Passant, probably a good point with reliability of lock.exe. I was already trying to lock mscoree.dll but got stuck a bit.. Tried `notepad >>mscoree.dll` but that only resulted in "Access is denied" ... Is there some easy way to lock mscoree.dll without coding my own tool for that purpose? I tried [Easy File Locker](http://www.xoslab.com/efl.html) but it neither was able to lock the mscoree.dll.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Today I accidently discovered a way to achieve this. Reboot seems to be always required when trying to perform installation multiple times using the same installer. So just follow these steps:

1. get .NET v4.0 web installer from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17851),
2. run the downloaded installer,
3. wait for installation to finish,
4. run the downloaded installation again,
5. you can choose whether to repair or remove, choose **repair**,
6. once .NET v4.0 is successfully repaired, it requires a reboot, bingo.

The restart due to locking mscoree.dll is probably not required because implementation of mscoree.dll is  now split into mscoree.dll and mscoreei.dll which is in .NET version specific folder and therefore restart is no longer needed. More info can be found [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2010/09/13/is-that-the-right-version-of-mscoreei-dll.aspx), long story short:

> We’ve seen significant numbers of machine reboots as part of .NET redist installation, typically due to needing to update a file that is in use. The most common file in use has been mscoree.dll, which is loaded by every single .NET application, and even some services such as MSI. As a result, we undertook the mscoree “split” to avoid machine reboots. By moving the shim implementation into a version-specific file, we are able to deploy a new version of mscoreei.dll (say in the v5.0 .NET folder, as part of .NET 5.0 installation), without touching the machine-wide mscoree.dll file.

So .NET v4.0 repair process needs to replace mscoreei.dll in the v4.0 folder so even this nifty feature with spliting the implementation of mscoree.dll will not help us here and restart will be required.